# embedded font in fop 0.93

Tags: encoding, utf-8, apache-fop

I use `fop 0.93` for transforming xml to pdf and I have a font problem
My xml have cyrillic characters so when I open the resulting pdf I got `##`

Here is my fop config file:

```
<fonts>    
    <font
        metrics-url="/FontMetrica/cour.xml"
        kerning="yes"
        embed-url="/Fonts/CourierNew.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="CourierNew" style="normal" weight="normal" />
    </font>
</fonts>
```

and java code:

```
fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File("fopConfig.xml"));
fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
```

In the result pdf file - properties-font used in this Document, I saw these fonts:

1. Courier
2. Courier-Bold

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I use  fop 0.93. My <font-base>///C:/Windows/</font-base>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the full path to configuration file. Or put fopConfig.xml in classpath.